# Tensorflow - re initializing weights and reshaping tensor of pretrained model

Tags: tensorflow

I am looking at the following example:
https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/4_Utils/save_restore_model.ipynb

I want to be able to reinitialize the weights of hidden layer 2 and reshape the final layer(out_layer) to be with 3 classes instead of 10.

I want to be able to do that on the second session - that means, after I restore the trained model.

My main objective is to learn how to do transfer learning in tensorflow and I think that by doing that to this example I would be able to learn that. Can you point me to what I should do? I really tried looking but couldn't find any similar example..

Answer (score -1):

I solved it.

It is possible to reinitialize the weights by doing the following:
The important part is set_value which receives the session, a tensorflow variable and the new weights value

```
def _convert_string_dtype(dtype):
    if dtype == 'float16':
        return tf.float16
    if dtype == 'float32':
        return tf.float32
    elif dtype == 'float64':
        return tf.float64
    elif dtype == 'int16':
        return tf.int16
    elif dtype == 'int32':
        return tf.int32
    elif dtype == 'int64':
        return tf.int64
    elif dtype == 'uint8':
        return tf.int8
    elif dtype == 'uint16':
        return tf.uint16
    else:
        raise ValueError('Unsupported dtype:', dtype)

def set_value(sess, x, value):
    """Sets the value of a variable, from a Numpy array.
    # Arguments
        x: Tensor to set to a new value.
        value: Value to set the tensor to, as a Numpy array
            (of the same shape).
    """
    value = np.asarray(value)
    tf_dtype = _convert_string_dtype(x.dtype.name.split('_')[0])
    if hasattr(x, '_assign_placeholder'):
        assign_placeholder = x._assign_placeholder
        assign_op = x._assign_op
    else:
        assign_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf_dtype, shape=value.shape)
        assign_op = x.assign(assign_placeholder)
        x._assign_placeholder = assign_placeholder
        x._assign_op = assign_op
    return sess.run(assign_op, feed_dict={assign_placeholder: value})

# Tensorflow variable name
tf_var_name ="h2_weights"
var = [var for var in tf.global_variables() if var.op.name==tf_var_name][0] 
var_shape = var.get_shape().as_list()

# Initialize to zero
new_weights = np.zeros(var_shape)

set_value(sess,var,new_weights)
```